# IE will not take full height of link background color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu, hyperlink

All the browsers are displaying my site good, only internet explorer doesn't.
I've got a menu with background color set in CSS, I've added padding to make sure there is room around the link itself.
Internet Explorer doesn't take the bottom padding.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="moduletable_menu">
  <ul class="nav menu">
     <li class="item-101 current active parent"><a href="/" >Reclamebureau</a></li>
     <li class="item-102"><a href="/contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
     <li class="item-125"><a href="/diensten.html" >Diensten</a></li>
     <li class="item-126"><a href="/portfolio.html" >Portfolio</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code for the hover and active state:

```
ul.menu li a:hover,
ul.menu li.active a,
ul.menu li.current a {
  display:inline;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #9a5574;
  z-index:10;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 21px 14px 50px 14px;
}
```

This is the website I'm talking about: www.appelmeule.com

Thank you very much

Comment: Which version of IE are you using ? Try Changing inline to inline-block

Comment: Hopely useful for you, [this article I've read](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Nice way of asking question..